# Get page title in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a UIWebView and want to show the page title. I did it with this code:

```
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(aWebView: UIWebView) {
    titleLabel?.text = aWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")!
  }
```

This works fine for most of the pages but there are some pages where not title is shown. For example `http://stackoverflow.com/users`. When I open this page in the browser the title is shown but not in my simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have nested loads happening due to redirects etc on some pages. Try tracking the loads and finishes so you know the last one has finished.

Set a counter to 0 when you request a page load. Increment this when a page load starts and decrement when a page load finishes or fails.

When the counter goes to 0, run your javascript.

Excuse my swift, but something like:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(aWebView: UIWebView) {
  self.webLoads++
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(aWebView: UIWebView) {
  self.webLoads--
  if (webLoads == 0){
    titleLabel?.text = aWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")!
  }
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView!, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError!){
  self.webLoads--;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it must be to do with the page content. You could try running the javascript once back at the main loop. Try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {titleLabel?.text = aWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.title")!}`

Comment: You need to do some debugging via the javascript and print out what is returned, so you know what is at fault. I would change the java script to always return something if the `document` or `document.title` is nil. Something like `"(document ? (document.title ? document.title : 'Untitled') : 'No Document')"` . Put in a break point on the javascript line and print the result. Also check how many times you enter viewDidFinishLoading.

Comment: I cannot update the javascript because it is a third party page which I load!

Comment: I mean change the javascript code in the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` call so it returns more information. e.g. `titleLabel?.text = aWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("(document ? (document.title ? (document.title == '' ? 'Empty String' : document.title) : 'Untitled') : 'No Document')")`